# What does a for loop within a list do in Python?

Tags: python, loops

Can someone explain the last line of this Python code snippet to me?

`Cell` is just another class. I don't understand how the `for` loop is being used to store `Cell` objects into the `Column` object.

```
class Column(object):

    def __init__(self, region, srcPos, pos):

        self.region = region
        self.cells = [Cell(self, i) for i in xrange(region.cellsPerCol)] #Please explain this line.
```

Comment: it is called a 'list comprehension'

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The line of code you are asking about is using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a list and assign the data collected in this list to `self.cells`.  It is equivalent to

```
self.cells = []
for i in xrange(region.cellsPerCol):
    self.cells.append(Cell(self, i))
```

***Explanation***:

To best explain *how* this works, a few simple examples might be instructive in helping you *understand* the code you have. If you are going to continue working with Python code, you will come across list comprehension again, and you may want to use it yourself.

Note, in the example below, both code segments are *equivalent* in that they create a `list` of values stored in list `myList`.

For instance:

```
myList = []
for i in range(10):
    myList.append(i)
```

is equivalent to

```
myList = [i for i in range(10)]
```

List comprehensions can be more complex too, so for instance if you had some condition that determined if values should go into a list you could also express this with list comprehension.

This example only collects even numbered values in the list:

```
myList = []
for i in range(10):
    if i%2 == 0:     # could be written as "if not i%2" more tersely
       myList.append(i)
```

and the equivalent list comprehension:

```
myList = [i for i in range(10) if i%2 == 0]
```

Two final notes:

- You can have "nested" list comrehensions, but they quickly become hard to comprehend :)
- List comprehension will run faster than the equivalent for-loop, and therefore is often a favorite with regular Python programmers who are concerned about efficiency.

Ok, one last example showing that you can also apply functions to the items you are iterating over in the list. This uses [float()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) to convert a list of strings to float values:

```
data = ['3', '7.4', '8.2']
new_data = [float(n) for n in data]
```

gives:

```
new_data
[3.0, 7.4, 8.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as if you did this:

```
def __init__(self, region, srcPos, pos):
    self.region = region
    self.cells = []
    for i in xrange(region.cellsPerCol):
        self.cells.append(Cell(self, i))
```

This is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).