# Can someone explain me the 5th line of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I could understand a little but I want the exact explanation of that particular line. I'm confused about the syntax.

Otherwise, I know how the code works and what is it doing, I just want to clarify my concept about the syntax.

Code :

```
import docx2txt

def extract_text_from_doc(doc_path):
    temp = docx2txt.process("resumes/Chinmaya_Kaundanya_Resume.docx")
    text = [line.replace('\t', ' ') for line in temp.split('\n') if line]
    return ' '.join(text)
```

Comment: I know how the code works and what is it doing. so what do you think what this line 5  is doing ?

Comment: Do you mean the line starting `text =` (line #5), or the `return` (the fifth line of actual code)? If the former, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479392/what-does-a-for-loop-within-a-list-do-in-python; that's a *list comprehension*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) version for:

```py
text = []
for line in temp.split('\n'):
    if line:
        text.append(line.replace('\t', ' '))
```

It iterates through `temp` line by line, if the line is not empty it replaces `'\t'` (tabs) with spaces, and puts the results in a the array `text`.

Answer (score 0):

it's basically a list comprehension

it will iterate through each line, checking if line is not empty then replace the tab character with spaces.