# Python: Can anyone explain "f for f in..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

can anyone explain in detail what this means? `f for f in...` for example

```
list = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isdir(f)]
print(list)
```

I understand the syntax of basic for loops, but I've seen this type of thing numerous times and I find it pretty confusing. I've been searching and all I can find is info on formatting. I just started in python around a month ago and am still learning. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a for loop within a list do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479392/what-does-a-for-loop-within-a-list-do-in-python)

Comment: Beside the point, but [don't use `list` as a variable name since it shadows the builtin `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77552/4518341). You could use `L` instead, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you want to create a list with values 0 to 100

```
list = [i for i in range(100)]
```

Here `i` will be added to the list while iterating from 0 to 100.

If you want any rule, you can use an `if` statement in the loop like:

```
list = [i for i in range(100) if i%2 == 0]
```

Here only numbers divisible by 2 will be added to the list because of the `if` statement.

Comment: FWIW, the easier way to do the non-filtered one is `list(range(100))`. Though `range` already supports most operations `list` does, so casting it might be redundant, but I digress.

Comment: I know that but I did not have anything to iterate over this is the reason I used but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
> applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
> some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
> iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
> certain condition.

Answer (score 3):

This is a list comprehension. This loop would normally be written like this:

```py
files = []
for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        files.append(f)
```

Comment: [Don't use `l` as a variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid); use `L` instead.

Comment: I would normally say to use something meaningful like `files = []` but i typed this on my cellphone and am lazy