# Why do we use like this?

Tags: python, list, class, split, strip

I am reading this CSV file and adding its value to a list of a class. Can you kindly explain how is it possible to use the strip and split function like this?

```
ba = []
for line in cvsfile:
    j = line.split(',')
    num, f, s, b = [i.strip() for i in j]
    name = A(num, f, s, b)
    ba.append(name)
```

I am confused at this part.

```
j = line.split(',')
num, f, s, b = [i.strip() for i in j]
```

By the way, my class name is A.

Please explain. Thanks in advance. Sorry for the language as English is not my first.

Comment: What specifically about those lines? The `num, f, s, b =` part?

Comment: Do you understand `num, f, s, b = [2, 3, 5, 8]`?

Comment: Yes, I understand that Matthias. I don't understand the usage of [i.strip() for i in j].

Comment: That's called a "list comprehension". Check out something like `[i for i in range(10)]` or `[i*i for i in range(10)]`.

Comment: See [What does a for loop within a list do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11479392/3890632)

Comment: I suspect you mean CSV (comma separated values) file, not a [CVS file](https://www.nongnu.org/cvs/). Have you looked at the Python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: Sorry I will edit it. CSV file.

Comment: Matthias. Thank you. It is list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file has values separated by commas and the program is reading in the file line by line. Consider the following example

```
line = 'Val1,Val2,Val3' # consider this is a line in the CSV file
```

Now, using `j = line.split(',')` will split the line at the commas and return back a list of the values splitted.

When you split `line` at `,`, you get a list equal to `['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']` which will now be assigned to `j`.

The `.strip()` method will remove any trailing or starting spaces from a string. For example,

```
s = '     hello      '
t = s.strip()
# now t is just equal to the string 'hello' without any spaces
```

`[i.strip() for i in j]` is creating a list of all values in `j`, but all spaces are removed from the values.

`num, s, f, b = [i.strip() for i in j]` is simply assigning the values inside the list to num, s, f and b.

Example,

```
a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# the above line assigns a to 1, b to 2, c to 3 and d to 4
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, Amtthias, mentioned it is called list comprehension.